# android AsyncTask in foreach

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

Have the following AsyncTask code:

```
private class checkChangesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
protected ProgressDialog mProgressDialog2; 
protected String _url = "", _idautor="", _idbook="";

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    this.mProgressDialog2 = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    this.mProgressDialog2.setMessage("Check changes ...");
    this.mProgressDialog2.setIndeterminate(false);
    this.mProgressDialog2.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    this.mProgressDialog2.setCancelable(true);
    this.mProgressDialog2.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    this.mProgressDialog2.setMax(100);
    this.mProgressDialog2.setProgress(0);
    this.mProgressDialog2.show();
}       

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Document doc = null;
    String _html = "";
    _idautor = params[0];
    _idbook = params[1];
    _url = params[2];
    try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(_url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
        Elements dd = doc.select("dd");

        int size = dd.size();
        int p = 1;
        for (Element src : dd) {
            this.mProgressDialog2.setProgress(p*100/size);
            if (p <= size-1){
                _html += src.outerHtml();
                ++p;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Jsoup.clean(_html, Whitelist.basic());           
} 
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {   
    if(!result.equals("")){
        String lastfile = readPageFile(_idautor + "_" + _idbook);
        if(!lastfile.equals(result)){
            savePageToFile(_idautor + "_" + _idbook, result);
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error checkChangesTask", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    this.mProgressDialog2.dismiss();
}
```

the previous code I call in a loop:

```
public void checkChanges() {
    String[][] db_books = db.selectAllBOOKS();
    if (db_books.length>0){
        for (int j = 0; j < db_books.length; j++){  
            new checkChangesTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, db_books[j][1], db_books[j][0], db_books[j][2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but the dialog does not display the correct value. First, it is worth it to 0% and then abruptly switches to 100%.

AsyncTask called in sequence (...executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR...).

If you run a AsyncTask not in the loop, all the displays are just perfect!

android: targetSdkVersion = "14"

I ask your help.

Comment: How this will show... you are showing more than one dialog at screen on same time... why asyntask in loop...?

Comment: I get a list of books (pages) from the database. And spending review - there are any updates on the Internet? I spend checking character by character. If there is a difference - then resave the file with the book.

Comment: So you can move the whole loop into single asynctask..

Comment: And if it is not possible to do?

Comment: Dear folk.. everything is possible. The logic which you are trying is not good... so change you logic. Or you can call all asynctask one by one. like if one is completed then call another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `onProgressUpdate()` inside the AsyncTask. Something like this (at a guess)

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

    this.mProgressDialog2.setProgress(progress[0] * 100/progress[1]);
}
```

And replace this line:

```
this.mProgressDialog2.setProgress(p*100/size);
```

With this:

```
 publishProgress(new int[]{p,size})
```