# Waiting until user actually sees something on the screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I've got a main Activity, an extra class for my fragment, and inside this fragment is an AsyncTask, which gathers data from various android library (Wifi SSID, BSSID, etc). When I start my app the app shows a blank screen, without any UI. Then after about 2 seconds, the whole data is being shown. I actually want to display my TextViews as "Not connected to a wifi network" in the background, while showing a ProgressDialog until the data is being displayed. I've got the ProgressDialog in my MainActivity, and calling it in my AsyncTask onProgressUpdate

```
MainActivity.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.c,
                                              "ProgressDialog Title",
                                              "ProgressDialog Body");
```

I'm updating my TextViews in the doInBackground methode (via another methode outside the Fragment)

```
((Activity) getActivity()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
```

[image: Blank Activity]

Comment: You tell what you are doing but have not asked any question. What is your problem?

Comment: My problem is that the Activity is blank for about 2 seconds (while the AsyncTask is being executed) and then I can see my TextViews etc. altough the AsyncTask is being executed in the onViewCreated methode

Comment: The textviews are declared in XML, right?  So can't you set the default string via the XML, and then when you have data prepared, just use the `.setText()` method of each textview?

Comment: Sounds like the code is occupying the UI thread afterall. Are you calling .get() on your AsyncTask? You are right about the textviews.

Comment: @nexus_2006: Yeah I am using the .setText() method, I will attach a picture so you know what I mean

Comment: @cYrixmorten: No not directly inside the AsyncTask, but I am using a static method I created called "getActivity()" which is inside my Activity, which just returns the Context of the MainActivity

Comment: The picture shows the app when it starts then after 2 seconds I can see my UI...

Comment: OK, onProgressUpdate is a called in UI thread... When I remove the ProgressDialog code, it works...

Comment: Remove the static getActivity() that is really not a good idea. I am working on an answer which hopefully can help you.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I need to access it that way, because my Fragment is in another class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be too big a comment so i'll just put it here.

Sounds like you are using both fragment and AsyncTask in an incorrect way. You should never do anything UI relevant in doInBackground.

Here is an example of what you could do.

I assume the following scenario:

- You have a main activity
- You have a fragment containing TextViews
- You wish to populate the TextViews after loading some data using AsyncTask with a progressDialog

The approach would be to:

1. Add the fragment in onCreate of your activity (if the fragment is not defined in the layout, then it will automatically be added).
2. Create the AsyncTask in your fragment like this:

   ```
   private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
   ProgressDialog progressDialog;
   //declare other objects as per your need
   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute()
   {
       // getActivity() is available in fragments and returns the activity to which it is attached
       progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

       progressDialog.setTitle("ProgressDialog Title");
       progressDialog.setMessage("ProgressDialog Body");
       progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true)
       progressDialog.setCancelable(false)
       progressDialog.show();

       //do initialization of required objects objects here                
   };      

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
   {   
       List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
       //do loading operation here  
       //add each of the texts you want to show in results
       return results;
   }       

   // onPostExecute runs on UI thread
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(List<String> results )
   {
       progressDialog.dismiss();
       // iterate results and add the text to your TextViews
       super.onPostExecute(result);
   };
   }
   ```
3. Start the AsyncTask in onCreate of your fragment:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       new LoadData().execute();
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }
   ```

This way you avoid calling directly back to your activity, which really should not be necessary in your scenario (unless I have misunderstood).

Otherwise please post all the relevant code and layouts.

Comment: This does not work unfortunately, the screen stays blank, I can't see the ProgressDialog at all!

Comment: @Tigger not true. can just be a simple indeterminate spinner

Comment: think I constructed to dialog in a wrong way. How about now? Is the activity still blank while loading ?

Comment: @cYrixmorten and moe2801 - Sorry, I assumed it was a progress bar of a known percentage. I have removed my comment as it was misleading.

Comment: @cYrixmorten: This doesn't work, the screen looks like in the picture, it's blank for 2 seconds, then when the AsyncTask finished I can see the ProgressDialog, for about 0.5 sec

Comment: Please add your code then. Something is taking the UI thread's attention for those 2 seconds.

Comment: I moved the .setText() lines to onPostExecute(), I also dismiss my ProgressDialog there. It's now working so that the screen isn't blank, but when the TextViews in the background get updated, the ProgressDialog (the spinner) freezes/doesn't move... Why's that?

Comment: I'm sorry it was my fault that your code didn't work, because I was doing .setText() in doInBackground()

Comment: Ok I got it, there was a leftover method blocking the main UI thread... Thanks a lot, I'm marking this as correct, because it actually helped me!

Answer (score 1):

This line:

> I'm updating my TextViews in the doInBackground methode

points to your problem. You need to use the AsyncTask method `onProgressUpdate()` to publish to the UI thread. You do not call `onProgressUpdate()` directly, instead you call `publishProgress()`.

Interestingly, I answered a similar question yesterday here: [android AsyncTask in foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113167/android-asynctask-in-foreach/20113458#20113458)

and it includes an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do.

(1) From the place you run the code that gathers data, you should first display the progress dialog.  Something like this:

```
busy = new ProgressDialog (this);
busy.setMessage (getString (R.string.busy));
busy.setIndeterminate (true);
busy.setCancelable (false);
busy.show();
```

(2) Then you start your data gathering.  This must be done in a separate thread (or Runnable).  Do something like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread ()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      ... gather data ...

      Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
      msg.what = LOADING_COMPLETE;
      msg.obj = null;
      handler.sendMessage (msg);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
      msg.what = LOADING_FAILED;
      msg.obj = e.getMessage(); // maybe pass this along to show to the user
      handler.sendMessage (msg);
    }

    // get rid of the progress dialog
    busy.dismiss();
    busy = null;
  }
}
```

(3) Add a handler to the activity to receive notification when data gathering is complete:

```
Handler handler = new Handler()
{
  @Override
  public void handleMessage (Message msg)
  {
    if (msg.what == LOADING_COMPLETE)
      loadingComplete ();
    else if (msg.what == LOADING_FAILED)
      loadingFailed ((String)msg.obj); 
  }
};
```

(4) Implement the handlers:

```
private void loadingComplete ()
{
  ...
}

private void loadingFailed (String errorMessage)
{
  ...
}
```

That's the essentials.

Comment: Why are you using a Thread instead of an AsyncTask? (just for understanding) I thought that an AsyncTask is better, because you don't have to implement a Handler...

Comment: I also think this is an overly complex way of doing exactly what AsyncTask achieves.

Comment: AsyncTask is fine too.  I simply haven't used it.